# Using DisplayFor inside a for each loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, html-helper

I have the following view:-

```
@foreach(var info in Model.Firewall.FirewallCustomers.OrderBy(a=>a.CustomerName)){

<td>@Html.DisplayFor(info.CustomerVLAN.VLANID)</td>
}
```

But I am unable to write the following

```
@Html.DisplayFor(info.CustomerVLAN.VLANID)</td>
```

I will get the following error:-

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly

So can anyone advice , how to use DisplayFor inside my foeach loop ?

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing ``var`` with the type of ``info`` in the ``foreach``

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`DisplayFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) needs an expression. Try this:

```
@foreach(var info in Model.Firewall.FirewallCustomers.OrderBy(a=>a.CustomerName)){
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => info.CustomerVLAN.VLANID)</td>
}
```

Here, `model` is a lambda expression parameter, and even though it's not actually used in the lambda expression, this syntax is needed to construct the expression.